# How was Virginia transformed from a society with slaves, to a slave society?

Tags: 18th-century, slavery, 17th-century, colonial-america

Not sure what the main answer to this question.

I know Bacon's rebellion changed the lives of many poor whites with no land.
Also, there were the slave laws which I need to do more research on.

Comment: You also may want to consider the influence of the originally separate slave society based in Charleston, South Carolina.

Comment: Please use [google](http://varnam.nationalinterest.in/2014/02/from-a-society-with-slaves-to-a-slave-society/) [first](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-difference-between-society-with-slaves-slave-306531).  Or the redoutable [Ta-Nehsi Coates](http://www.theatlantic.com/personal/archive/2011/09/the-slave-society-defined/244581/).

Comment: I've added my vote to close not for "trivia..." but for "unclear". I'm not sure I understand what is being asked, beyond the words given in the title. OP: an "on hold" is not the same as "closed", if you'll clean up your question, and perhaps add more explanation in the body, it could easily be reopened.